# Click a button to show menu, click button again to hide menu

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to be able to show a menu when clicking a button, and hiding the same menu when clicking the button again. I am not sure how to do this, any help would be great! My click function is below.

```
Private Sub btnMeasure_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnMeasure.Click
    Try
        If Constants.MapAction.SetMapAction(mapActionEnum.Measure) Then
            Dim measureForm As New frmMeasure(mpMapView)
            measureForm.Show()


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Constants.WriteToErrorLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType.Name,
                            System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name,
                            ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: If you click your button `me` will become TopMost and `frmMeasure` is going to be one level behind the calling form. I understand you want to hide `frmMeasure` altogether? When you say menu, you really mean Form?

Comment: Hi - yes! Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Declare/Set the form at Class scope, not in this sub:

```
Public Class YourClass
   Dim measureForm As New frmMeasure(mpMapView)
```

and your button click event:

```
Private Sub btnMeasure_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMeasure.Click
    If measureForm.Visible Then
        measureForm.Hide()
    Else
        measureForm.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for the edge case of when the form gets closed and you need to create a new instance.  I think you're using WPF, but here is how it would look in WinForms:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private measureForm As frmMeasure = Nothing

    Private Sub btnMeasure_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnMeasure.Click
        Try
            If Constants.MapAction.SetMapAction(mapActionEnum.Measure) Then
                If IsNothing(measureForm) OrElse measureForm.IsDisposed Then
                    measureForm = New frmMeasure(mpMapView)
                    measureForm.Show()
                ElseIf Not measureForm.Visible Then
                    measureForm.Show()
                Else
                    measureForm.Hide()
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'Constants.WriteToErrorLog(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod.DeclaringType.Name,
            '                    System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name,
            '                    ex)
        End Try
    End Sub

End Class
```